# Easy question: What does it mean if a variable is highlighted in red in the XCode debugger?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm having some trouble squashing some bugs in my iPhone application and I have come to the realisation that I'm not entirely clear on what the significance of a variable being highlighted in red?

Does it mean the variable no longer exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the value has changed since the last time a breakpoint was reached or your last step, to make it easy to see how your variables are changing over the lifetime of your program.

Comment: It's seems that the red text I'm referring to is in the summary column. I don't have any break-points set, the program is just crashing at that point... 

i.e identifier | NSCFString * | 0x54270 | [red]J20TextCellMiddle[/red]

What does the red signify here as I didn't set a previous breakpoint?